# Threading in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, user-interface, .net-4.0

I have been writing ASP.NET web application for years now, but haven't really worked on large windows forms projects.  I now need to work on one, so I am looking on some pointers on how a large windows forms project should ideally be structured.  More specifically, I would like to know how to handle multiple threads.  Assume you have a process which takes some time to complete - you do not want to have the ui window frozen and not responding.  So that logic needs to move in a separate thread.  If this thread accesses the UI, then it will cause exceptions.  Invoke seems to do the trick, but looks very ugly and cumbersome to write and read!

So, in reality, what are the best practices?  What type of threads should one launch, and how should these threads be split between UI and logic? Any sample code to get started?

Comment: Have a look at the BackgroundWorker class, if using Invoke seems messy to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a short way to use the backgroundworker

```
        public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true; //set to true to fire the progress-changed event
        worker.DoWork += doWork;
        worker.ProgressChanged += progressChanged;
    }

    void progressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int progress = e.ProgressPercentage; //Progress-Value
        object userState = e.UserState; //can be used to pass values to the progress-changed-event
    }

    void doWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        object argument = e.Argument; //Parameters for the call
        bool cancel = e.Cancel; //Boolean-Value for cancel work
        object result = e.Result; //Object for a return-value
    }
```

Comment: And there is an event called RunWorkerCompleted which is fired when the worker is finished.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you use a different thread you will have to switch back to the UI thread when touching the UI.

[someForm.BeginInvoke()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3.aspx) can do this but there are more options.

The BackgroundWorker can do the switching for you.

In .NET 4.5/ C# 5 you can use [async/await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443%28v=VS.110%29.aspx); the continuation will be called on the original thread.

In general, try to untangle the logic as much as you can from the UI so you do not need to switch thread too often.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to achieve UI responsiveness, execute long running tasks, achieve parallelism. You have to select the right way for your application -

[This article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/winforms.shtml) by Jon Skeet is always a bonus to start with.

1. You can call Synchronous methods Asynchronously using [any of these styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc.aspx) as per your application design and requirements
2. More [difficult situations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c9txz50.aspx), such as coordinating the work of multiple threads, or handling threads that block
3. There are a number of ways to expose asynchronous features to client code. [Read here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hkasytyf) for the Event-based Asynchronous Pattern - which prescribes the recommended way for classes to present asynchronous behavior.
4. [Background Worker](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/88390/MVP-VM-Model-View-Presenter-ViewModel-with-Data-Bi) comes in handy when you have a single long running task.

Hope this gives you a head start.