# Windows Forms Project with Threading

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have read a LOT of material about Windows Form projects not supporting MTA.  I get it.  However, I also have read about Background worker, async/await and BeginInvoke use with such solutions.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991868/threading-in-windows-forms) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991868/threading-in-windows-forms?rq=1) are just a couple of examples.  [Here's one](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/03/01/asynchronous-msmq-processing.aspx) that even uses MSMQ.  Some of the examples I have reviewed go way back to VB6 days.

I need to augment a Windows Form project with code to interact with a vendor service via API calls that could benefit from async capability.  This being 2014, what is the best way to approach this?  I use VB NET and have VS 2010 for my development.

Ideally, I would like to create a class library with the logic to interact with the vendor and just return the results to my Windows Form project.  Can that be done?

Comment: Can you upgrade VS? `async`/`await` require VS2012.

Comment: @Stephen: Unfortunately, VS2012 is not an option at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that MTA is not supported doesn't mean that you can't use multiple threads. The MTA model is just one way to use multiple threads, but because it's difficult to implement objects for that model, Windows Form uses the STA model instead.

The important effect of this is just that it means that the main thread in the application takes care of everything that has to do with the user interface. You can start as many threads as you like/need, but whenever anything from those threads needs to be displayed in the user interface, they have to use the `Invoke` method to let that update be done in the main thread.

There are already asynchronous method in the framework, for example the `BeginRead` and `BeginWrite` methods in the `System.IO.FileStream` class. You can have a look at those for some hints on how asynchronous methods are used in the framework.

If the API is synchronous, you would make asynchronous methods by simply starting a new thread that does the API call and then executes a callback method when it is done. As it's that thread that is waiting for the response, the call doesn't occupy the main thread.

Comment: Thank you @Guffa for your reply.  This does help clear up some of the mystery.  Do you have some code to illustrate your preference?

Comment: Hm... what preference?

Comment: Also, what about using the await operator.  Doesn't MSFT seem to be favoring this approach for asynchronous processing lately?

Comment: @Ebassador: The `await` operator is used with asynchronous methods that returns a `Task` object. That would be a natural choise if your API does that, but then it would already be asynchronous.